# How to enable VSTO for all users in MSI?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, vsto, ms-office

I have an MSI (in VS 2010) that is creating a VSTO (4.0) (targeting .NET 4.0; for Office 2007) in the x86 Program Files folder, and everything seems to be fine.  The registry correctly shows the VSTO, the VSTO's files are installed in the correct location, and after I load the Office application, I can see the plugin in the add-ins.

When I try to enable it in Office, I get the following error:

"This add-in is installed for all users on this computer, and can only be connected or disconnected by an administrator."

It will be installed by an administrator for all users -- is there a custom action or something I can do in the MSI to ensure that it gets registered/connected for all users?

I've double-checked the registry -- the LoadBehavior for the VSTO is still 3 and without problems...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Based on my experience (.net 2.0 office 2003), VSTO can not be installed to "ALL users" using an administrator account. It can only be installed under the user's account by the user itself. (I've tried about everything I could found during that time). In the end, I rebuild my VSTO project using `shared add-in` instead.

Comment: Whenever I try to install for "Just me" it doesn't show up in the Office Addins at all...  Maybe this is related to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As a lesson learned, I discovered that because we were signing the package, the reason it didn't work was because the certificate was NOT installed on the machine.  As such, I had to manually install the certificate for signing and then I could easily make it install "For Everyone" or "Just Me" without a hitch.